# Lower bound for the order of a group element

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I would like to know how to find a lower bound of an element in a large group.
Let's say I have an element $x\in G$ and that $|G|=N$ is very large, say $\mathcal{O}(10^{300})$.

To find the order of $x$, I could use Lagrange's theorem that the order of $x$ must divide $N$. But this involves finding the prime decomposition of $N$ which is no mean feat.

My current way of finding the lower bound is to do a partial decomposition of $N$ and checking that $x$ when raised to a power of multiples of the factors, do not yield the identity. From that, I would be able to get a lower bound for the order of $x$.

Can you see a faster or other way of finding a lower bound? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Unless the group $G$ has special properties, there is no other way than testing successively for each integer $k\geq 1$ whether $k$ divides $|G|$, add if so, to test whether $x^k$ is the identity. That’s because the order could be any divisor of $|G|$.

Comment: Hi @EwanDelanoy, thank you for your comment. I would say that the method in the question is a refinement of your method. I was hoping that we could perhaps modify existing methods of solving the DLP to evaluate a lower bound. I think Euler tried to do so and came up with the Euler Totient Theorem with Carmichael following that.

Comment: How is your group $G$ given? This makes a difference. Consider for instance the last-but-one paragraph of this page http://goo.gl/O6MW16 of the Handbook of Computational Group Theory by Derek F. Holt, Bettina Eick and Eamonn A. O'Brien.

Comment: Hello @AndreasCaranti, thank you for your comment. The group in question is the abelian group $C_{p-1}\times C_{q-1}$ where $p$ and $q$ are large primes. The solution to this problem will help safeguard RSA from fixed point attacks where computing $e^{k-1}$ where $k$ is the order would yield the private exponent.

Comment: @yanbo, thanks, sounds quite interesting!